# calculate distance between coordinates in java

Tags: java, distance, latitude-longitude

I have a `getNearestSuperMarket` method that returns in a list the nearest super markets close to my location. The results I get from the `calculateDistance` method are wrong. Do you know which is the most efficient way to fix it?

```
limit=9000000 //in meters

public List<Market> getNearestMarkets(String lat1, String lng1) throws Exception{ 
    flat1 = Float.parseFloat(lat1);
    flng1 = Float.parseFloat(lng1);         
    list_markets2=getAllMarkets(); //returns all the markets from the database

    for ( Market ma: list_markets2){

        x1=ma.getLatitude_market();
        y1=Float.parseFloat(x1);

        x2=ma.getLongtitude_market();
        y2=Float.parseFloat(x2);

        dist=calculateDistance(flat1,flng1,y1,y2);
        try{
            if ( dist< limit ){
                ma.setDistance(dist);
                list_nearest_markets.add(ma);
            }
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex){
            throw new Exception("somethings happened"+ex.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e0){
            errorMessages ="error: "+e0.getMessage();
            throw new Exception(e0.getMessage());
        }
    }

    return list_nearest_markets;

}//end of method


public float calculateDistance(float flat1, float flng1, float flat2, float flng2) throws Exception{

    try{

        double earthRadius = 6371000; //meters
        double dLat = Math.toRadians(flat2-flat1);
        double dLng = Math.toRadians(flng2-flng1);
        double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
        Math.cos(Math.toRadians(flat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(flat2)) *
        Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
        double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
        float dist = (float) (earthRadius * c);
        return dist; 

    }catch(Exception e10){
        throw new Exception("error"+e10.getMessage());
    }
}//end of method
```

Comment: What results are you seeing, and what results do you expect to see?

Comment: Near my place it shows me that the nearest market is 100000 meters far away

Comment: Break down the problem piece by piece. Are the latitude and longitutes the program receives correct? If yes, the formula you're using to calculate the distance between to points on a sphere (given the coordinates lat1,long1 and lat2,long2) are wrong. Where did you get these formulas from?

Comment: @Maximilian i m having for example 37.984797 Latitude and 23.729647 Longitude from the place I am and from the database i get latitude and longitude from all markets( in my database they are declared as string)

Comment: So, have you verified that the coordinates of the markets are correct? You should provide atleast a pair of inputs sothat we can see what result you should get. The formula for the distance-calculation, where'd you get it from? The formula on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance#Formulas) looks different, it should be something like http://pastebin.com/4wJ8EUgx

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt formula being used here is probably correct, see this link http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/haversine/

Comment: @Mary try reducing the value of `limit` it's currently 9000 kilometers. Your program just filters out the places which are closer than 9000 kilometers. 100000 meters is just 100 KM which is very small value compared to 9000KM.

Comment: @Mary Also, please give us the code for the `getNearestSuperMarket()` function, we're just seeing `getNearestMarkets()`. It would be a pretty trivial error if your mistake was in the `getNearestSuperMarket()` function, which gives you the market farthest away from you by mistake. If the formula and its usage for the distance-calculation is correct, the error lies either in the source data or the above function.